# How can I solve the following ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

$$C\frac{dT}{dt}=-\sigma T(t)^{4}+(1-\alpha)Q$$ I need help to solve the above pde where $C,\alpha ,Q$ are constants, I'm really unsure on how to even start to solve it

Comment: It looks like an ODE to me. I presume $t(t)$ is a typo?

Comment: Yes sorry that is a typo thanks

Comment: Is $*$ multiplication? If so you should write $\sigma T(t)^4$ instead. If it is not you need to say so.

Comment: It is multiplication not convolutions

Comment: $\sigma$ is a constant as well? You can separate variables, but the integral is gross

Comment: Yes $\sigma$ is a constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have written it, your problem is an ODE not a PDE as $T$ is a function of only one variable. As you only have one function and everything else is a constant you can solve using separation of variables.

For example let $p=(1-\alpha)Q$. We can can separate variables as

\begin{align}
\frac{C}{-\sigma T^4+p} \frac{d T}{dt}=1
\end{align} 
The tricky part is integration of the left side. Also see

- http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Summary_of_exact_solutions

The second link we be more helpful as the it shows how to express the solution as an integral. I beilive this form is going to be part of the expected answer as this is a very diffcult integral.

Comment: should $d$ be $C$?

Comment: yes, my mistake

Comment: Please accept my answer, if you found it satisfactory.